# Responsive Menu Pro Issues

Tags: css

Please refer to project: http://www.lightertaste.com/

If you condense the screen and/or open via media, the responsive menu is not working correctly. I'm using the Responsive Menu Pro Plugin.

1) When the menu appears, the search bar appears over the top of the menu link (I have the menu link set to left and the search box appearing after the menu).

2) The entire menu is linking my FAQ page and I have NO idea why.

3) When you open the menu, it overlaps the top bar (where you open the menu) - you can only see it for a few seconds before it transfers you to the FAQ page.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your menu is wrapped in `<a>` tag. i.e. `<a href="http://www.lightertaste.com/faq/">...</a>`. That's why when you click on menu it redirects you to the page specified in its `href` attribute.

Comment: How do I remove this?

Comment: Change your `HTML` code.

Comment: Not sure how to do that. The menu is installed via plug-in.